# Kernel Panic, can't boot into Ubuntu after Windows did some updates

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel

I installed Windows first and then I immediately installed Ubuntu and Debian. After I installed Windows I didn't configure it at all, i.e didn't install any drivers or anything. But just made sure that Linux and Windows were booting. However after couple days I decided to setup Windows and configure it. So I installed all the drivers and all the needed updates. Also Windows was fixing some "errors" when booting, which I had no idea what they were. However after I was done with Windows I tried to boot into either Ubuntu or Debian but I couldn't at all! I always get a Kernel Panic!

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Debian Jessie.

My motherboard is `Asus m5a97 r2.0`. It's one of those weird boards that has this weird `UEFI` thingy. I had a lot of trouble with this when I tried to install Ubuntu in the very far past, ie not this install. So I thought this could be the problem, so I went into the BIOS and disabled Secure Boot. I also boot only from the HDD which doesn't have the UEFI icon on it in the BIOS.

I'm completely clueless and I have no idea what to do to be able to boot into Ubuntu again. In this post I attached the kernel panic that i get.

[image]

Comment: The `corrupted stack end detected inside scheduler` is like a driver or the kernel is damaged… Idk, but I'd advice to run a check of Ubuntu and Debian file systems.

Comment: @Hi-Angel how come both Ubuntu and Debian gets damaged in the same way ... i still feel it's the UEFI thing doing some crap

Comment: Can you boot from live media?

Comment: @JackTwain first, you had the UEFI thing from the very beginning, and it have little to do with installed OSes at all. And, if systems were working, then after *Windows update (not the UEFI update)* they broke, perhaps it have something to do with Windows, not the UEFI. Second: if UEFI managed to relegate the boot to a system *(which is the case because you see how Ubuntu and Debian trying to start)*, its job is done, it can't suddenly interfere in the middle of a boot. Overall, I very doubt that the problem you're having have anything with UEFI at all.